# How to enable spell checker in web browser control for IE10

Tags: internet-explorer, webbrowser-control, spell-checking

I am trying to enable the spell checker feature coming with IE10 in my own application hosting web browser control. According to this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330735(v=vs.85).aspx#spellcheck , all I have to do is create a value myapp.exe and set it to 1 under the following registry key:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING

or

HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_SPELLCHECKING

However, I tried it and it doesn't work. If you have been able to get it working, please share your experience.

Comment: Just checking, when you say it doesn't work, do you mean that you tried it in one of the following:
(1) textArea elements, (2) elements with a contentEditable attribute set to true, (3) elements with a spellcheck attribute set to true?

Comment: If you are on windows 7, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's switched on as standard, but is buggy for me, it works on some pages and in some text boxes but not all, it works fine for me on the IE test site :

http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Browser/SpellChecking/

Does that work for you?